# HashMap throws ConcurrentModification even if using iterator.remove() to remove node

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I've got a `ConcurrentModificationException` when operating a `HashMap`. The code is as following:

```
    Iterator<Integer> iterator =cacheMap.keySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        if(iterator.next() == target) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

The only operations I used were remove like that and `cacheMap.put(node)`. And the methods were all called in the main thread, including `onCreate()` method of `Activity`, `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask` and `handleMessage(Message msg)` method in the handler of main thread.

But occasionally, `ConcurrentModificationException` was thrown in `iterator.next()` when I use the method above to remove a node, although it's really few.

I've reviewed the relevant method in HashMap. It's like this:

```
@Override public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    return (ks != null) ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet());
}

private final class KeyIterator extends HashIterator
        implements Iterator<K> {
    public K next() { return nextEntry().key; }
}

private abstract class HashIterator {
    int nextIndex;
    HashMapEntry<K, V> nextEntry = entryForNullKey;
    HashMapEntry<K, V> lastEntryReturned;
    int expectedModCount = modCount;

    HashIterator() {
        if (nextEntry == null) {
            HashMapEntry<K, V>[] tab = table;
            HashMapEntry<K, V> next = null;
            while (next == null && nextIndex < tab.length) {
                next = tab[nextIndex++];
            }
            nextEntry = next;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return nextEntry != null;
    }

    HashMapEntry<K, V> nextEntry() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if (nextEntry == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        HashMapEntry<K, V> entryToReturn = nextEntry;
        HashMapEntry<K, V>[] tab = table;
        HashMapEntry<K, V> next = entryToReturn.next;
        while (next == null && nextIndex < tab.length) {
            next = tab[nextIndex++];
        }
        nextEntry = next;
        return lastEntryReturned = entryToReturn;
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (lastEntryReturned == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        HashMap.this.remove(lastEntryReturned.key);
        lastEntryReturned = null;
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    }
}

@Override public V remove(Object key) {
    if (key == null) {
        return removeNullKey();
    }
    int hash = secondaryHash(key);
    HashMapEntry<K, V>[] tab = table;
    int index = hash & (tab.length - 1);
    for (HashMapEntry<K, V> e = tab[index], prev = null;
            e != null; prev = e, e = e.next) {
        if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
            if (prev == null) {
                tab[index] = e.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = e.next;
            }
            modCount++;
            size--;
            postRemove(e);
            return e.value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private V removeNullKey() {
    HashMapEntry<K, V> e = entryForNullKey;
    if (e == null) {
        return null;
    }
    entryForNullKey = null;
    modCount++;
    size--;
    postRemove(e);
    return e.value;
}

/**
 * Subclass overrides this method to unlink entry.
 */
void postRemove(HashMapEntry<K, V> e) { }
```

The `modCount` and the `expectedModeCount` is checked when calling `nextEntry()` and `remove`. But it seems impossible for the difference of the two integer if `iterator.remove()` is called to remove node.

Comment: Would it, by any chance, the code that you are using the iterator is actually on another thread? Showing code of how you use the `cacheMap` may helps too.

Comment: The code you show here is the code for the map's entry set, not the keyset; try and use an `Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Whatever>>` over the map directly and .remove() from that (although the javadoc says it should not make a difference).

Comment: The `KeySet` is like this, `private final class KeyIterator extends HashIterator
            implements Iterator<K> {
        public K next() { return nextEntry().key; }
    }`     So I don't think it matters.

Comment: And what about the code for `.remove()`? Well, anyway, give it a try. If it works, you probably have discovered a bug in Android's `HashMap`!

Comment: Why are you iterating over a `HashMap` to delete from it? Why are you iterating over it at all? That's already a sign of a design error.

Comment: Thank you very much for indicating a better design!

Answer (score 1):

Just use cacheMap.remove(target).

From the Docs:

*public V remove(Object key)
Removes the mapping for the specified key from this map if present.*

And remember a HashMap can only store one object for a given key, so no need to iterate over all values.

Answer (score -3):

you can not iterate a collection and remove items from it.

use:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
Iterator<Integer> iterator =cacheMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer key = iterator.next();
        if(key == target) {
            set.add(key );
        }
    }
    cacheMap.rmoveAll(set);
```

Comment: That is wrong. You can. Otherwise, `Iterator` would not define `.remove()`!